# setTimeout when PageLoad complete - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, pageload

I love this plugin:
http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos

The **iPhoto (ish)** one works beautifully on my site so far. I click a button, the block appears and the new page loads.

However, I'd like to **set the setTimeout value to be when the next page has completed loading**. So once the page fully loads, the block disappears.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you send a link so we can see your website?

Comment: I really wish I could, but it's on a local server and I can't provide access just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must be using ajax to reload the content.

You could do:

```
$('#TheLastElementThatYouReload').ready(function () {

// set timeout / hide block

});
```

I'm unsure why you need a timeout, but this way you won't need it.

Comment: Hi Kryptonite. Can you possibly show me how I would use this in the malsup example in the OP? What would I replace `#TheLastElementThatYouReload` with?

Comment: It doesn't really fit the example. I just mean that when you are finish reloading your page yuo should call $.unblockUI. The best place to do this is after you have reloaded your dom elements. I would need to see your page to say what the ID of that element is. setTimeout is used in the malsup example as a quick and easy way of hiding the popup.

Answer (score 1):

If you load the new page via ajax, in this page:

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#overview

there is this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

which sort of binds itself to every ajax load. I guess instead of setTimeout you should put an event to the end of loading a page since setTimeout works only with time and "guessing" a page's loading time does not make much sense

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi daghan! Thanks for your prompt response. I'm not the hottest with Jquery. Are you able to show me perhaps in a jsfiddle what I should be looking to do here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are loading the pages but if you can send a function when the page does load, do something like this:

```
function page_loaded(){

    $.blockUI({ 
        message: 'page loaded!'
    }); 

}
```